# VPS freezes every few days (rcu_sched_state detected stall on CPU x)

Tags: ubuntu, cpu

**Background:** I have an Ubuntu 12.04 (64bit) in Xen virtualization environment. 1 GB RAM, 1 processor.

Every few days I get the following error message:

> rcu_sched_state detected stall on cpu 0 (t=xxxxx jiffies)

Before when I had Ubuntu 11.01; after a distribution upgrade the error is still occurring.

The server runs (don't ask, I'm just a Linux rookie developer who has to "maintain" this): OEMPro, Apache2/MySQL/PHP, on main website with 2 Wordpress blogs. Daily page-loads are not more then 5-7K.

There are no huge peaks of memory or CPU usage before the stall (as tracked on our Munin graphs).

#### Questions

1. The freeze can be caused via huge sql queries?
2. How can I fix it?

Comment: Is this still a problem that you are facing?